# Failed to restart redis-server.service: Unit redis-server.service not found

Tags: node.js, redis

Tried to start redis-server but got:

> 26195:C 27 Aug 17:05:11.684 # Warning: no config file specified, using
>   the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server
>   /path/to/redis.conf
>
> 26195:M 27 Aug 17:05:11.684 * Increased maximum number of open files
>   to 10032 (it was originally set to 1024).
>
> 26195:M 27 Aug 17:05:11.685 # Creating Server TCP listening socket
>   *:6379: bind: Address already in use

Ran `lsof -wni tcp:3000` and killed the local host and tried restarting redis-server again and got the same above error.

Tried: `ps -aux | grep redis` (output below), then `sudo kill -9 6379`

> nick4896 12238  0.0  0.1  41432  9048 ?        Sl   Aug26   0:14
>   redis-server *:6379
>
> nick4896 26304  0.0  0.0  21300   984 pts/21   S+   17:08   0:00 grep
>   --color=auto redis

And ran `sudo service redis-server restart`, and got:

> Failed to restart redis-server.service: Unit redis-server.service not
>   found.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 83):

The problem is that symlink `redis-server.service` to `redis.service` was deleted.
Command

> sudo systemctl enable redis-server

creates the symlink:

> Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/redis.service → /lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service.

Comment: While this might solve the issue, it's best to include an explanation as well.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this, I would suggest `systemctl daemon-reload`

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but to complete Igor Kavzov's answer, this is the code to enter at the terminal:

```
sudo ln /lib/systemd/system/redis.service  /etc/systemd/system/redis-server.service
```